# TextView.setText() in ListView.onScroll gives warning "requestLayout() improperly called"

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `ListView` with a scroll listener. I want to programmatically set a `TextView`'s text inside of the `onScroll`. It works, but it repeats the following warning rapidly.

> requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.TextView{ ... } during second layout pass: posting in next frame ...
>
> requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.TextView{ ... } during layout: running second layout pass

Here's the code I'm referring to:

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView v, int firstVisibleItem, 
                     int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

    myTextView.setText("test text");
}
```

I did a bit of poking around but I never could find a clear explanation of what "**requestLayout() improperly called**"  means. If anybody has ideas, they would be much appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to do as follows:

```
myTextView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
          myTextView.setText("test text");
    }
});
```